# Import Python module based on argument fails with ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to dynamically import a python-based SQL query module from a sub-folder, and that folder is obtained by using the argparse module.

My project structure :

```
main_file.py
Data_Projects/
   ITA_data/
      __init__.py
      sqlfile.py
   UK_data/
      __init__.py
      sqlfile.py
```

Within main_file.py is the argparse module with the argument 'dir' containing the location of the specified directory i.e.

```
parser.add_argument('--dir', default='Data_Projects/ITA_data/', type=str,
                        help="set the data directory")
```

My understanding thus far is that modules should be imported at the top and to import just one sql query I would use:
`from Data_Project.ITA_data import sqlfile`

I know I can't set the import statement after the args have been defined, so how can I keep the format correct with the imports at the top, and yet retrospectively update this with the arguments that get defined afterwards?

I've tried to assign:

```
sqlfile = __import__(in_arg.dir + 'sqlfile.py')
```

However I'm getting the following error:

> *** ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Data_Projects/ITA_data/sqlfile'

I've tried using things like

```
os.path.join(Path(__file__).resolve().parents[0], in_arg.dir + 'sqlfile')
```

When I try just:

```
__import__('Data_Projects')  # works fine
__import__('Data_Projects/ITA_data')  # doesn't work - ModuleNotFound
```

And as a check to verify I'm not crazy:

```
os.path.exists('Data_Projects/ITA_Data/sqlfile.py')  # True
os.path.exists(in_arg.dir + 'sqlfile.py')  # True
```

Comment: There is no limitation that the import must be done at the top, you can import a module at the scope (before) it is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with

```
import argparse
parser = ...
parser.add_argument('data', choices=['UK', 'ITA'])
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.dir == 'UK':
    import UK_data as data
elif args.dir == 'ITA':
    import ITA_data as data
else ...
```

You could refine this with functions and `__name__` etc.  But a conditional import is ok, just so long as it occurs before the `data` module is used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `__import__(filename: str)` function instead of `import` statement. It does the same:

```
# option 1
import foo as bar
# option 2
bar = __import__('foo')
```

If you need to import from aside, you need to add your directory to `module search paths`. There are several ways to achieve that, depending on your version of Python. You can find them all in great post:

[How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: Thanks - can I add bar after the args have been defined then, effectively having import statements in the middle of my module?

Comment: You can put this statement wherever you want

Comment: I've updated my answer, would you be able to help again? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by using :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd() + "/" + in_arg.dir)
```

This sets the PYTHONPATH variable to include the directory I want (which changes depending on the argument) to use to search for the file.

From there using grapes help it was a case of doing:

```
sqlfile = __import__('sqlfile')
```

And from there I could use the variable to perform the relevant sql query.